# How to send object in ksoap2 request

Tags: android, object, request, ksoap2, ksoap

I'm trying to pass an object to web service using ksopa2 library. I'm trying something like this:

```
        RangeInfo controllingArea = new RangeInfo();
        controllingArea.setLow(txtControllingAreaSearch.getText().toString());

        PropertyInfo propertyControllingArea = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyControllingArea.setType(new RangeInfo().getClass());
        propertyControllingArea.setName("IControllingarea");
        propertyControllingArea.setValue(controllingArea);
        request.addProperty(propertyControllingArea);

        PropertyInfo maxNoOfHits = new PropertyInfo();
        maxNoOfHits.setValue(txtMaxNoHitsSearch.getText().toString());
        maxNoOfHits.setName("IMaxnoofhits");
        maxNoOfHits.setType(PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS);

        request.addProperty(maxNoOfHits);
```

My RangeInfo class is like this:

```
  public String sign = "I";
public String option = "EQ";
public String low;
public String high;

public RangeInfo(){}

public RangeInfo(SoapObject soapObject)
{
    if (soapObject == null)
        return;
    if (soapObject.hasProperty("Sign"))
    {
        Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("Sign");
        if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
            SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
            sign = j.toString();
        }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof String){
            sign = (String) obj;
        }
    }
    if (soapObject.hasProperty("Option"))
    {
        Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("Option");
        if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
            SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
            option = j.toString();
        }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof String){
            option = (String) obj;
        }
    }
    if (soapObject.hasProperty("Low"))
    {
        Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("Low");
        if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
            SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
            low = j.toString();
        }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof String){
            low = (String) obj;
        }
    }
    if (soapObject.hasProperty("High"))
    {
        Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("High");
        if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
            SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
            high = j.toString();
        }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof String){
            high = (String) obj;
        }
    }
}
@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    switch(arg0){
        case 0:
            return sign;
        case 1:
            return option;
        case 2:
            return low;
        case 3:
            return high;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch(index){
        case 0:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Sign";
            break;
        case 1:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Option";
            break;
        case 2:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Low";
            break;
        case 3:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "High";
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
}

public void setSign(String sign) {
    this.sign = sign;
}

public void setOption(String option) {
    this.option = option;
}

public void setLow(String low) {
    this.low = low;
}

public void setHigh(String high) {
    this.high = high;
}
```

In the server side I'm getting value of "IMaxnoofhits" variable, but "IControllingarea" is always null!!!

Someone has passed or imagine what could be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: could u check the request that you send from android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys,

I solved it by my self. Here is what i did. And it is working to send complex object to the request.

```
                RangeInfo controllingArea = new RangeInfo();
                controllingArea.setLow("Value");
                controllingArea.setHigh("Value");

                PropertyInfo item = new PropertyInfo();
                item.setType(controllingArea.getClass());
                item.setName("item");
                item.setValue(controllingArea);

                SoapObject object1 = new SoapObject("","IControllingarea");
                object1.addProperty(item);
                request.addSoapObject(object1);


                PropertyInfo maxNoOfHits = new PropertyInfo();
                maxNoOfHits.setValue(txtMaxNoHitsSearch.getText().toString());
                maxNoOfHits.setName("IMaxnoofhits");
                maxNoOfHits.setType(PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS);

                request.addProperty(maxNoOfHits);
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like when you instantiate your `RangeInfo controllingArea = new RangeInfo();` class you're not passing in a SoapObject so you're just calling the empty constructor, instead of the second constructor which has all your code.

Also, I know this isn't a part of your question but your `maxNoOfHits` parameter is set to the Integer class, even though `.setValue` looks like you're passing in a String.